# How to skip validation on update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a custom validation on model, it allows me to check uniqueness of 1 field but related to another model, something like (1,2,3,4,5) -> User1, (1,2,3,4,5) -> User2, so because a value can actually exists for 2 different users but not 2 times for the same users I had to use a custom validator! Here is my code:

```
def codigoDuplicado?
    @invinveacCommit = Invinveac.where(codproveedor: codproveedor, ndocumento: ndocumento).first
    if @invinveacCommit != nil
        errors.add(:ndocumento, "Ya existe un movimiento con el mismo codigo para el proveedor seleccionado.")
    end
end
```

My problem is, it is trying to validate even for update method where I dont need to validate that code, is there any way to skip that validation for update action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:on` keyword when setting up the validation

So in your model, I assume you have something like:

```
validate :codigoDuplicado?
```

You can make this

```
validate :codigoDuplicado?, on: :create
```

Comment: Yes, I do, Awesome! I´ll try it now!